# Export Multiple Crystal Reports ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, crystal-reports, export

I want to export 2 different reports when I click an Export button.  The problem is the routine only fires once and I only get one report to print out.  Am I doing something wrong? I think it has something to do with the HTTPResponse, but I'm not sure.

Here's my code:

```
Dim badgeSize As Integer = 0 'Drop Down selection

    Dim badgeData As New DataSet 'Visitor Badge Data
    Dim badgeEmployeeData As New DataSet 'Employee Badge Data
    Dim badgeTotals As Integer = 0 'Totals for both

    badgeSize = ddlBadgeSize.SelectedValue

    ' Get Visitor Data
    badgeData = _DatabaseAccess.GetProjectReportData(sessionInfo.myEventID, sessionInfo.EventCreator)
    ' Get Employee Data
    badgeEmployeeData = _DatabaseAccess.GetProjectReportEmployeeData(sessionInfo.myEventID, sessionInfo.EventCreator)
    'Obtain Totals
    badgeTotals = badgeData.Tables(0).Rows.Count + badgeEmployeeData.Tables(0).Rows.Count

    If badgeTotals = 0 Then
        ShowMessage("There are no badges to print.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If badgeSize.Equals(0) Then 'Small 

        If badgeEmployeeData.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            If badgeEmployeeData.Tables(0).Rows.Count >= 6 Then
                PrintProjectBadges(badgeEmployeeData, "Employee", badgeSize)
            Else
                PrintStandardDymo(badgeEmployeeData, "Employee", 1)
            End If
        End If

        If badgeData.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            If badgeData.Tables(0).Rows.Count >= 6 Then
                PrintProjectBadges(badgeData, "Visitor", badgeSize)
            Else
                PrintStandardDymo(badgeData, "Visitor", 1)
            End If
        End If
   else
     'do somethign else
   endif
```

And the Report Code:

```
Private Sub PrintProjectBadges(ByVal theData As DataSet, ByVal badgeType As String, ByVal badgeSize As Integer)
        Dim ourReport As New ReportDocument
        Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo(SetCrystalConnection)

        If badgeSize = 0 Then
            Try
                If badgeType = "Visitor" Then
                    ourReport.Load(Server.MapPath("SmallProjectBadge.rpt"), OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault) 'LIVE SERVER USE
                Else
                    ourReport.Load(Server.MapPath("SmallProjectEmployeeBadge.rpt"), OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault) 'LIVE SERVER USE
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim TraceList As New ArrayList
                TraceList.Add("DBLog")
                DatabaseAccess.WriteToErrorLog("Visitor Registration", "Printing Project Badges", ex.Message, TraceEventType.Information, 1, TraceList)
                Exit Sub
            End Try

            ourReport.SetDataSource(theData.Tables("Project"))
        Else
            'Do somethign else...
        End If

        Response.Buffer = True
        'Clear the response content and headers
        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.ClearHeaders()

        SetLogon(ourReport, crConnectionInfo)

        'Export the Report to Response stream in PDF format and file name Customers
        ourReport.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "Visitor_Badges")
        Response.End()
        'Response.Close()


    End Sub
```

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The response can only send a single file at a time -- to export both, you'd need to export them to the local disk, and combine them into something like a ZIP file to then send that back to the client.